# How do I access the last index of each list of list?

Tags: python, list

How do you access the last index of each list of list?

```
list = [['hey', 'who', '09'], ['lol', 'ae', '12'], ['e', 's', '1']]
                        ^                     ^                ^
```

Comment: `list[-2][-2]` to get `ae` but surely this is a duplicate of something. Search before you ask :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this this way -

```
for l in list:
    # Here l is the element of list
    # As l is also a list, the you can access last element
    # of l using negative indexing
    print l[-1]
```

If you want to create another list using those you can do -

```
new = [l[-1] for l in list]
```

Above code assumes that every element of `list` is also a non-empty list. If it may happen that they can be other than list, you may want to check if it is indeed a list. Check also for empty lists.

Also you may want to avoid using list as variable name

Comment: More than " assumes that every element of list is also a list", it also assumes none of the sublists are empty!  If one is empty, you get `IndexError: list index out of range` from the `l[-1]`.

Answer (score 2):

By using a list comprehension and indexing with `[-1]`

```
lst = [['hey', 'who', '09'], ['lol', 'ae', '12'], ['e', 's', '1']]
new_lst = [x[-1] for x in lst]
```

**Side note: you shouldn't name your list `list`.**

Comment: But should you? No

Comment: My answer says 'can',so no compulsion and not a good practice

Comment: @bigbounty How about now?

Comment: @abccd how is this answer different from kuro's answer ?

Comment: @Pavan his original answer only contains the for loop, while mine was using a list comprehension. He added the list comprehension part 4 mins ago

Comment: Suffers from the same problem that if one of the sublists is empty, you get `IndexError: list index out of range` from the x[-1].

Comment: Usually when it's not a problem in the OP's sample list, it wouldn't be a problem. But what you said is a valid point.

Answer (score 1):

I've no issue with the other answers, except both the title and text asked:

> How do you access the ***last index*** of each list of list?

The other answers showed how to access the ***last element*** of each list of list.

To access the ***last index*** of each list of list, try:

```
>>> my_list = [['hey', 'who', '09'], ['lol', 'ae'], ['e']]
>>> my_indicies = [len(sub_list) - 1 for sub_list in my_list]
>>> my_indicies
[2, 1, 0]
```

Returns -1 as the last index if the sublist is empty and can't be indexed.